# How can be minimize inter packet and switching latency in EtherCAT protocol?

Tags: microcontroller, ethercat

I am trying to connect multiple microcontroller board(slave node) through a main supervisor(master node) via EtherCAT protocol. All the slave nodes will be connected through a switch. So, Is there any interpacket latency or switching latency in switching hub while exchanging the data to one switch port to another switch port? Is there any mechanism to improvise these latencies as minimal as possible?

Answer (score 1):

What switch are you planning on using? Typically there is no need for a switch in an EtherCAT network as you can daisy chain the slave devices together. A slave device only adds about 1us of latency so this would be the best way to keep latency as minimal as possible. Is there a reason you can't daisy chain?

Comment: As per my connection ....All the microcontroller will be connected in a star topology(One to many connections). Then the problem will arise...in switching. For multiple slaves, we can use any kind of network switches. Please give some solutions regarding this problem.

Comment: There are some EtherCAT switch options which will help to minimize the latency: https://www.ethercat.org/en/products/B67A0DF8EC004ECC8CC4BC20A124D1D0.htm, https://www.ethercat.org/en/products/D6B00855DAC24E8FA62F7681BF526568.htm, https://www.ethercat.org/en/products/EE5FC6F6F5344F65B0400FE06ED45826.htm, https://www.ethercat.org/en/products/3651E6B60E8C4677AA25D34208274729.htm.